# meaning of ${#PIDS} in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to understand a shell script.Following script is just a small portion of big script

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `pgrep -f libflashplayer.so`
do
  PIDS=$PIDS$i","
done
echo ${#PIDS}
PIDS=`echo ${PIDS:0:${#PIDS}-1}`
```

I am not clear with what does

```
echo ${#PIDS}
PIDS=`echo ${PIDS:0:${#PIDS}-1}`
```

in above script mean?

** UPDATE **

After having understood the replies below 
here is the input

```
#npviewer. 2768 deel   11u   REG                7,0 19218930   262562 /tmp/FlashXX2j3xhT (deleted)
#npviewer. 2768 deel   12u   REG                7,0 32352982   262837 /tmp/FlashXX6R4nAq (deleted)
#npviewer. 2768 deel   17u   REG                7,0 27289825   262824 /tmp/FlashXXuVBqbu (deleted)
#npviewer. 2768 deel   18u   REG                7,0 21632133   262825 /tmp/FlashXXneoS8s (deleted)
```

and this input is given on following script

```
for i in `lsof -np $PIDS | grep deleted | grep /tmp/Fl*`
do
     PID=`echo $i | cut -d " " -f 2`
     FD=`echo $i | cut -d " " -f 6`
     FD=`echo ${FD:0:${#FD}-1}`
     echo $FD
done
```

the output is

```
11u
12u
17u
18
```

as per my understanding the output should be

```
11
12
17
18
```

So why is that not so?

Comment: It loses the final comma from the list - obscurely.

Comment: Alternatively, you can to the same thing with `PIDS=${PIDS%,}`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler how does it looses comma? I am not able to understand that part.

Comment: It gives you the substring from 0 to length -1, dropping the last character, which is a trailing comma.

Comment: @ ${#parameter} was a new thing for me.I have updated the question now please see.

Comment: see below for a reply to your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It counts the number of characters in the PIDS string, then trims the last comma off the end of the string.

```
# cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

PIDS="1,2,3,4,5,"

echo "${PIDS}"
echo ${#PIDS}
echo "${PIDS:0:${#PIDS}-1}"
# ./a.sh
1,2,3,4,5,
10
1,2,3,4,5
```

In reply to your update, your output looks kind of weird to me. Shouldn't you be displaying token 4 instead of 6 in the second "cut"? Unless maybe I'm mis-understanding your input data. Here's what I got:

```
# cat a.dat
#npviewer. 2768 deel   11u   REG                7,0 19218930   262562 /tmp/FlashXX2j3xhT (deleted) 
#npviewer. 2768 deel   12u   REG                7,0 32352982   262837 /tmp/FlashXX6R4nAq (deleted) 
#npviewer. 2768 deel   17u   REG                7,0 27289825   262824 /tmp/FlashXXuVBqbu (deleted) 
#npviewer. 2768 deel   18u   REG                7,0 21632133   262825 /tmp/FlashXXneoS8s (deleted) 
# cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read i; do
  PID=`echo $i | cut -d " " -f 2`
  FD=`echo $i | cut -d " " -f 4`  
  FD=`echo ${FD:0:${#FD}-1}`
  echo $FD
done < a.dat

# ./a.sh
11
12
17
18
```

Okay now I get exactly what you are asking and because I was on a Solaris box earlier and I'm on a Linux box now, I get different results. So I guess the exact syntax can vary depending on what shell/platform you are on.

But I did get it working on my Linux box running Firefox. The difference is that on my configuration, no matter how many windows OR tabs I open, it still falls under the same process ID (I'm running Xubuntu with Firefox 3.6). Ignoring that, we can still do what you are trying to do by running through the processes one at a time and extracting the file descriptors for each iteration. See example below:

```
user@host:~$ cat a
for p in `pgrep -f libflashplayer.so`
do
  for f in `lsof -p $p | grep tmp/Fl | cut -d " " -f 6 | while read fd; do echo ${fd%[a-z]}; done`
  do
    echo "cp /proc/${p}/fd/${f} ${HOME}/${p}_${f}.flvdone"
  done
done

user@host:~$ ./a
cp /proc/17492/fd/16 /home/user/17492_16.flvdone
cp /proc/17492/fd/19 /home/user/17492_19.flvdone
cp /proc/17492/fd/20 /home/user/17492_20.flvdone
```

Note that I didn't include the "delete" grep expression because it doesn't immediately delete the file under my configuration. See if you can modify this script to do what you are trying to do. I couldn't get the ${PIDS:0:${#PIDS}-1} part working on my machine either which is why I switch substring commands to use the "%" operator instead. It worked that way.

Comment: hmmm, I was also expecting what you mention how ever this is not happening.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I see you're using Bourne shell (#!/bin/sh) to execute your script but I was unable to run it properly doing the same. But after switching to bash (#!/bin/bash) it worked fine.

Comment: read this here http://sathyaphoenix.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/flash-player-10-2-workaround-to-copy-video-files/ the problem is PID consists of many values and FD also consists of many values.Try to run this script after opening many youtube pages you will be able to understand what I am asking.

Comment: By looping through your PIDs one at a time using an outer loop, you can make your script simpler. See my edited response.

Comment: hmmm I think you made a mistake fd or f in while loop?

Comment: Not sure, but I ran it exactly as you see above. And it worked on my box. But like I said, you may have to play around to get the script to get it working on yours. The exact same commands I ran on a Solaris 10 machine using bash didn't work on my Xubuntu machine bash. So a little tweaking may be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Searching the [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for "${#":

> `${#parameter}`
>
> The length in characters of the expanded value of
>   *parameter* is substituted. If *parameter* is `*` or `@`, the value
>   substituted is the number of positional parameters. If *parameter* is an
>   array name subscripted by `*` or `@`, the value substituted is the
>   number of elements in the array.

Comment: ok i got ${# from your link now I have updated the question now please see.